# SwiftUI: using `presentationDetents(_:)` on `.sheet` does not update its height

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a sheet with an intrinsic height. Following [this](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/) excellent article, I am already reading the height of the view I want to present as a sheet.

Basically, my approach is as follows:

1. present the sheet with a custom height, that's held in a `@State` property: `.presentationDetents([.height(sheetHeight)])`
2. I try to retrieve the intrinsic height of my view with `readSize(onChange:)`
3. my thinking is that when I assign that height to my `@State` property, the height will update

Now, I do recognize that there is a massive flaw in my thinking: me handing down the height with `presentationDetents(_:)` means that the height will *not* be intrinsic but rather stay with the size I hand down–which is `.zero` in my case…

So here's my question: how can I get the **intrinsic** height of the view I want to present as a sheet here?

Here's the whole code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showBottomSheet = false
    @State private var sheetHeight = Double.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Show bottom sheet") {
                showBottomSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showBottomSheet) {
            BottomSheetView()
                .readSize { newSize in
                    print(newSize)
                    sheetHeight = newSize.height
                }
                .presentationDetents([.height(sheetHeight)])
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct BottomSheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Button 1") { /*Perform stuff*/ }
            Button("Button 2") { /*Perform other stuff*/ }
        }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}

extension View {
  func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Color.clear
          .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
  }
}
```

PS I also did realise while banging my head against the wall that a much better approach in my specific use case is probably to use the new `confirmationDialog(_:isPresented:titleVisibility:actions:)`–as this is excactly what I want to achieve. **Nonetheless I'd be interested in how to resolve this when using `.sheet`**, if only to educate me (and perhaps others?) on how to get the intrinsic size here.

Comment: you need to use `.presentationDetents(Set<PresentationDetent>, selection: Binding<PresentationDetent>)` and update selection in order to update height by setting new value to binding, something like: `selectedDetent = .height(sheetHeight)`

Comment: and store your selected detent in separate variable `@State private var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .medium`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no flaw in your thinking, the code is right and will create a sheet with the intrinsic height of `BottomSheetView`. The problem here is that `Form` *doesn't have* an intrinsic height. In fact, if you change `BottomSheetView` to the followings a minimally sized sheet **will** appear.

```
...
VStack {
    Button("Button 1") { /*Perform stuff*/ }
    Button("Button 2") { /*Perform other stuff*/ }
}
...
```

This is happening because `Form` wants to fill its container but its container, `BottomSheetView`, wants to constrain to its child. Since they're both competing for essentially the same information, the height falls back to your default of 0.

With that in mind, if you want to keep the styling of Form, the simplest solution would be to add a minimum height like so:

```
...
Form {
    Button("Button 1") { /*Perform stuff*/ }
    Button("Button 2") { /*Perform other stuff*/ }
}
.frame(minHeight: 200)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation–so I do understand now that `Form` won't work here because it does not have an intrinsic size. `.frame(minHeight: 200)` does not work for me either though because doing that, I will fix the size to that...
I wonder whether a rendering in the background with a clear `VStack` version of the content displayed would work–I was not able to do that so far though...

Comment: Having said that–the bounty is well deserved though because at least now I learned that certain layouts just don't have an intrinsic size.

Comment: Specifying a frame size still doesn't work with presentationDetents.